# $x_1$ such that given sequence $(x_n)$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ be a sequence in $\mathbb R$ such that $|4-x_{n+1}|<q|4-x_n|^2$, $\ q>0$

Under what circumstances for the initial value $x_1$ can we guarantee that $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ converges?

Comment: Iterate what you have, so $$|4-x_{n+1}| < q^2|4-x_{n-1}|^{2\cdot 2} < \dots$$

Comment: @Dzoooks Don't we have $|4-x_{n+1}|<q|4-x_n|^2<q|q|4-x_{n-1}|^2|^2=q^3|4-x_{n-1}|^4<...$?

Answer (score -1):

One can show by induction that
$$ \forall n\in\mathbb{N},\,|4-x_n|\leqslant q^n|4-x_0|^{2^n} $$
If $x_0\in]3,5[$, then $|4-x_0|<1$ and $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}x_n=4$, if $x_0\in\{3,5\}$, then $|4-x_0|=1$ and $(x_n)$ converges if $q<1$, in this case the limit is $4$. If $x_0\notin[3,5]$, then $|x_0-4|>1$ and $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}{|x_0-4|^{2^n}}=+\infty$, we can't say anything.

Comment: We only know an upper bound for $|4-x_n|$, not a lower bound so we can not say that $|4-x_{n+1}|$ is greater than anything. Your discussion of convergence is correct, so I upvoted.

Comment: @Tuvasbien You meant $\{3,5\}$ and $[3,5]$ instead of $\{4,5\}$ and $[4,5]$

Comment: Thanks, fixed it !

Comment: @Tuvasbien Can you tell me why my recursion is wrong:
$|4-x_{n+1}|<q\color{red}{|4-x_n|}^2<q|\color{red}{q|4-x_{n-1}|^2}|^2=q^3|4-x_{n-1}|^4<\ldots<q^{2^n-1}|4-x_1|^{2^n}$